# Efficient way to replace chars in a string (java)?

Tags: java, string, replace, char, stringbuilder

I'm writing a small JAVA program which:

- takes a text as a String
- takes 2 arrays of chars

What im trying to do will sound like "find and replace" but it is not the same so i thought its important to clear it.

Anyway I want to take this text, find if any char from the first array match a char in the text and if so, replace it with the matching char (according to index) from the second char array.

I'll explain with an example:
lets say my text (String) is: "java is awesome!";
i have 2 arrays (char[]):  "absm" and "!@*$".

The wished result is to change 'a' to '!' , 'b' to '@' and so on..
meaning the resulted text will be:

**"java is awesome!" changed to -> "j@v@ i* @w*o$e!"**

**What is the most efficient way of doing this and why?** 
I thought about looping the text, but then i found it not so efficient.

(**StringBuilder**/String class can be used)

Comment: Let us see what you have done so far

Comment: If you want to have `a` replaced by `!`, how do get `j@v@`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    for(int i = 0; i<text.length(); i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < firstCharArray.length;j++)
        {
            if (sb.charAt(i) == firstCharArray[j])
            {
                sb.setCharAt(i, secondCharArray[j]);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

This way is efficient because it uses a StringBuilder to change the characters in place (if you used Strings you would have to create new ones each time because they are immutable.) Also it minimizes the amount of passes you have to do (1 pass through the text string and n passes through the first array where n = text.length())

Comment: Okay this is sort of what I was trying to do.
I just tested your code, it worked perfectly! 

Thanks a lot.

**A little question: ** this code is looping each char in the text and for every char it loops the first char array. meanning for the second char in the text we'll loop again the first char, im guessing there's no other way? :S

Comment: What if the second char in the text was the first char in the array?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what u meant? Maybe it's my fault i just read what i wrote to u last post, anyway ill clear what i meant... 

lets say i have a string with 4 length and two arrays while the two of them are same size lets say 2 length.

at first we iterate the 1/4 char of text and we go through the whole array (x2)
then we iterate the 2/4 char.. and so on

we keep checking same options again and again so i wasnt sure how efficient it is..

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for [StringUtils.replaceEach](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceEach%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), at least as a reference.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what OP is looking for.

Comment: The OP asked for efficient.  This takes arrays of variable-length strings, not characters, which makes it somewhat inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

How efficient do you need it to be? Are you doing this for hundreds, thousands, millions of words???

I don't know if it's the most efficent, but you could use the string `indexOf()` method on each of your possible tokens, it will tell you if it's there, and then you can replace that index at the same time with the corresponding char from the other array.

Codewise, something like (this is half pseudo code by the way):

```
for(each of first array) {
    int temp = YourString.indexOf(current array field);
    if (temp >=0) {
        replace with other array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the 2 arrays you have in a Map

```
Map<Character, Character> //or Map of Strings
```

where the key is "a", "b" etc... and the value is the character you want to substitute with - "@" etc....

Then simply replace the keys in your String with the values.

Comment: Thanks but this example is too advanced since I'm not supposed to use this object.

Comment: No problem. Just something to think about later on.

Answer (score 1):

For small stuff like this, an indexOf() search is likely to be faster than a map, while "avoiding" the inner loop of the accepted answer.  Of course, the loop is still there, inside String.indexOf(), but it's likely to be optimized to a fare-thee-well by the JIT-compiler, because it's so heavily used.

```
static String replaceChars(String source, String from, String to)
{
    StringBuilder dest = new StringBuilder(source);
    for ( int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++ )
    {
        int foundAt = from.indexOf(source.charAt(i));
        if ( foundAt >= 0 )
            dest.setCharAt(i,to.charAt(foundAt));
    }
    return dest.toString();
}
```

Update: The Oracle/Sun JIT uses [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) on at least some processors for indexOf(), making it even faster than one would guess.

Comment: I tried accepted solution and your solution. And I found that your solution run much faster (2 time). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since the only way to know if a character should be replaced is to check it, you (or any util method) have to loop through the whole text, character after the other. You can never achieve better complexity than **O(n)** (n be the number of characters in the text).

Answer (score 0):

This utility class that **replaces a char or a group of chars of a String**. It is equivalent to bash `tr` and perl `tr///`, aka, transliterate.

```java
/**
 * Utility class that replaces chars of a String, aka, transliterate.
 * 
 * It's equivalent to bash 'tr' and perl 'tr///'.
 *
 */
public class ReplaceChars {

    public static String replace(String string, String from, String to) {
        return new String(replace(string.toCharArray(), from.toCharArray(), to.toCharArray()));
    }

    public static char[] replace(char[] chars, char[] from, char[] to) {

        char[] output = chars.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < from.length; j++) {
                if (output[i] == from[j]) {
                    output[i] = to[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    /**
     * For tests!
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Example from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher
        String string = "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG";
        String from = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String to = "XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW";

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Cesar cypher: " + string);
        System.out.println("Result:       " + ReplaceChars.replace(string, from, to));
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Cesar cypher: THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
Result:       QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD
```